# How write a function that returns values of different types?

Tags: haskell, types

The title of the question asks the core question. Here's the context for *why* I need something like this.

I'm dealing with a JSON-RPC interface over a Websocket. This means that the request-response cycle is completely asynchronous. When I send out a a request, I give it a unique ID, which the async-response includes (to help tie the request-response together).

Now, I need to parse the response JSON to a Haskell object using Aeson. Whichever way I structure it, I will need a function having the following type-signature at some point in my code:

```
rpcId2HaskellType :: String -> a
```

Where `a` is not every type under-the-sun, but a set of few known types that I'm expecting in response.

One solution I could think of, was to create an algebraic data type and use that as the return type for `rpcId2HaskellType`

```
data UnnecessaryAlgebraicDataType = ResponseType1 | ResponseType1 | ResponseType3
rpcId2HaskellType :: String -> UnnecessaryAlgebraicDataType
```

But, I'm not convinced that this is the best approach. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is the [FromJSON](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON) typeclass in aeson.

So in your case: `rpcId2HaskellType :: FromJSON a => String -> a`

However I'm willing to bet the `rpcId` has a consistent type in your protocol, so it should be up to your input functions to do that conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases.  If you know what type you are expecting at any particular use of `rpcId2HaskellType` you could use a type class that works exactly like the `Read` type class.

The other case is if you need to analyze the result to know what type you have and then you do different logic depending on that.  In that case, an algebraic data type is probably the best way of representing that.

There is another approach for this latter case using existential data types, but it is almost always a bad idea.  The idea behind it isn't too terrible (and is very common in OO programming) which is to have the returned value "know" how to do whatever it is you want to do with it itself.  Then your code just becomes asking it to do that thing.  In FP, though, it's usually better to have data be dumb.

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing as I don't have enough information to proove it,  but I don't think you are asking the right question.

I assume your JSON-RPC looks something like this:

`request.json`

```
{ message-id: "asec-ureh-asho-fcon-tent"
, content: { timestamp: "2016-01-31T10:23:10.123456"
           , command: { name: "mycommand"
                      , parameters: [..]
                      }
           }
}
```

`response.json`

```
{ message-id: "asec-ureh-asho-fthi-scon-tent"
, content: { timestamp: "2016-01-31T10:26:10.123456"
           , result: {..}
           , original-id: "asec-ureh-asho-fcon-tent"
           }
}
```

then I don't understand why you need to convert the `rpc-id` or `message-id` as this is just the hash of the content, this is most likely to be unique as it includes a (unique) timestamp as long as you leave out hash collisions of your considerations.

For the command I would always use an algebraic data type (ADT) so my server side logic is captured in haskell and I want to restrict the execution of "all" commands to the set at hand.

I don't think you want to avoid the writing of ADT's for this, but maybe think it's too much effort - which would lead me to an answer sidestepping your question and advise you to maybe write some template haskell that generates your ADTs for you.

PS.: I am writing this, knowing that you already got two good answers that help you proceeding in the direction you are asking, but wanting to give you a different point of view.

PPS.: `aeson` has some great capabilities to automatically derive the `fromJSON` and `toJSON` instances - see the [package description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.10.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell it is not possible to write a function that returns values of different types. The reason is that Haskell is statically typed.

This fails:

```hs
  :{
  g 1 = 2
  g 2 = "3"
  :}
```

But you can create your own ADT type.

This works:

```hs
  data IntString = IString String | IntS Int deriving Show
  :{
  g :: Int -> IntString
  g 1 = IntS 2
  g 2 = IString "3"
  :}
```